# Iterate over Database table row and store values in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, caching, .net-4.5

I want to implement a Dictionary cache in my program. How can I store the database result seen in the image below in a Dictionary Collection ?

I want to iterate over the Database table and store the content of LanguageName and IsoCode columns in a Dictionary like this `Dictionary<LanguageName,IsoCode>`.

My database (ctlang) looks like this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
private string GetLanguageForIsoCode(string isoCode)
    {

        //check the isocode column and return the corresponding language
        using (var unitOfWork = dataAccessUnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {   
            //need to call every time the sql query
            string query = "SELECT languagename FROM ctlang WHERE isocode='" + isoCode + "'";
            List<string> result = unitOfWork.OwEntities.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query).ToList();

            if (result.FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                return result.FirstOrDefault();
            }

            //if language not available in Database, fallback to German as default language
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de");
            //displayName = Deutsch
            return CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de").NativeName;
        }
    }
```

Bonus question: How can I search for a key in a dictionary using the value ?

Comment: It would be nice if I get the reason for -1, I could then improve my question.

Comment: You have a really nice SQL injection in your query.

Comment: `isoCode = "'; DROP TABLE ctlang;";`

Comment: @MatthewWhited if you look at the answer below I solved the SQL Injection  problem with the use of Entity Framework. Hope that makes you happy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem. In my Database the Table with the languages is named CTLANG and the columns are LANGUAGENAME and ISOCODE. I wanted to map these to into a Dictionary collection. So that at the end the dictionary looks like this:  ["LanguageName","IsoCode"].

```
 private static Dictionary<string, string> languageToIsoCode; //dictionary cache
 private void InitializeLanguageCacheDictionary()
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = dataAccessUnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            languageToIsoCode = (from p in unitOfWork.OwEntities.CTLANG
                                 select new {p.LANGUAGENAME, p.ISOCODE}).ToDictionary(p => p.LANGUAGENAME, p => p.ISOCODE);
        }
    }
```

Thanks to @D.Petrov I also found a way to search for the key in a dictionary and give its value back.

And this is how I optimized my method to use the dictionary cache.

```
private string GetLanguageForIsoCode(string isoCode)
    {
        if (languageToIsoCode == null)//if cache empty initialize it
        {
            InitializeLanguageCacheDictionary();
        }

        //searches inside the dictionary, look for value and then return key
        //might be bad if there are more than one value asigned to a key
        //because value does not habe to be unique
        string languageFromIsoCodeFromCache = languageToIsoCode.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value == isoCode).Key;

        if (languageFromIsoCodeFromCache == null)
        {
            //fallback and use the German language as default
            return CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de").NativeName;
        }

        return languageFromIsoCodeFromCache;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is. There is no problem in returning a key by its value, the only issue would be that there could *theoretically* be more than one key assigned to that value, since the key is what matters. But in your *particular* case that should be no problem, since only one isocode represents one language. So there would be no problem to make it like that, with dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> languagesAndKeys = new Dictionary<string, string>();  //Create it
```

Then you can search for keys/values like that:

```
string myValueByKey = languagesAndKeys["myKey"]; //getting value by key is easy
string myKeyByValue = languagesAndKeys.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value == "myValue").Key; //getting the key of the FIRST matching value/or returning the default type. You'll need a check to be sure.
```

Afterwards, you can easily load the data from the sql table into the dictionary. For this goal, you can either use a temporary datatable with dataadapter, which will work well as long as the table is not that big, or you can use a DataReader to loop trough rows in the sql table one by one. I'm gonna be using a temp DataTable:

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM ctlang";    //As far as I saw your cmd text in the code example, you may still want to take a look tho
string connectionString = "";   //fill the connection string according to your SQL server data
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, connectionString);
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dTable);

foreach(DataRow row in dTable.Rows)
    languagesAndKeys.Add(row[1].ToString(), row[0].ToString());//second column as a key, first column as a value - just like the structure of your table.
```

Comment: But how can I add the language and the ISOcode in the Dictionary collection from my Database ?

Comment: I know how to create a Dictionary collection, but I have trouble to instantiate it with my Database values.

Comment: @Devid I've updated my answer with an example approach of how to fill your dictionary using a temporary DataTable. There are other ways as well, but since your table is not that big, this would be fine.

Comment: The myKeyByValue helped me a lot.  Thanks +1

Comment: @Devid It's actually present overall in the internet, so no problem :D 
I hope you've understood what you can do with your sql table to maintain your data. If something is unclear, I'll be glad if I could help further.

Comment: I found a nicer way to for the database part  :)